# Checkbox marked with click in link

Tags: html

Well, I have a question on how to make this here:

I am wanting to make when the person click the "Text one"
and then the "checkbox" it is checked  and the link opens in a new tab, the same for the "Text two" and so on ...

image:

[image]

code:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <a href="LinkURL" target="_blank">
 <input type="checkbox" name="link1" value="link"> Text one</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="LinkURL" target="_blank">
<input type="checkbox" name="link2" value="link"> Text two</a>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to label and jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('label[for=link]').on('click', function(){
    alert('write here code');
window.location.href= 'http://www.rohitazad.com';
  });
  
  $('label[for=link2]').on('click', function(){
    alert('write here code 2');
window.location.href= 'http://www.rohitazad.com';
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  
 <input type="checkbox" name="link1" value="link" id="link"><label for="link">Text one</label>
<br>
<br>
  
<input type="checkbox" name="link2" value="link" id="link2"> <label for="link2">
Text two</label>

</form>
```

Comment: Adding the label with help with the checking part, however you will still need to use some javascript to open the url afterwards.

Comment: This is a good way, is almost perfect, I wonder to make the "href" open in a new tab, I tried to change the "window.location" to "window.open"  but apparently is not working, you have a solution?

Comment: @Matheus Used to this window.open("http://www.w3schools.com"); Example here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open

Comment: I is working perfectly, I was wrong in my tests but now I saw my mistake and the "window.open (" url ")," is working, thank you very

Answer (score 2):

you will need to add `label` with `for="xx"` and `id="xx"` for `input`

**Note** both the values should be the same for & id value

```
<a href="LinkURL" target="_blank">
    <input type="checkbox" name="link1" value="link" id="txt1">
    <label for="txt1">Text one</label>
</a>
```

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <a href="LinkURL" target="_blank">
    <input type="checkbox" name="link1" value="link" id="txt1">
    <label for="txt1">Text one</label>
  </a>
</form>
```

Or you can wrap `input` with `label`

```
<a href="LinkURL" target="_blank">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="link2" value="link">Text two</label>
</a>
```

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <a href="LinkURL" target="_blank">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="link2" value="link">Text two</label>
  </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go this way:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  <a href="LinkURL" target="_blank"  data-input='link1'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="link1" value="link"> Text one</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="#" data-input='link2'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="link2" value="link"> Text two</a>

</form>

<script>
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var input = $(this).attr('data-input');
  var checkbox = $('input:checkbox[name=' + input + ']');
  checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));;
})
</script>
```

The link is togglable. Then only thing I would change would be put some class on the links and reach than as `$('a.class')` instead `$('a')`

https://jsfiddle.net/yv7q5jb5/

Answer (score 1):

Add `label` tag

```
    <form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
<label>
    <a href="LinkURL" target="_blank">
        <input type="checkbox" name="link1" value="link"> Text one
    </a>
</label>
<br>
<br>
<label>
    <a href="LinkURL" target="_blank">
        <input type="checkbox" name="link2" value="link"> Text two
    </a>
</label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mb941zeL/2/